# While loop executing too many times

Tags: while-loop

this program reads text files, and in this case, reads this one:

```
Sam

5 0 0 0

Dave

5 5 0 0

Bill

5 -5 0 0

Louise

3 3 5 0
```

Early in my program, I execute the following while loop:

```
            int count = 0;


        while (input.hasNextLine())
        {

            count++;

            if (count % 2 == 1) //for every other line, reads the name
            {
                String line = input.nextLine(); 
                names.add(line); //puts name into array
            }

            if (count % 2 == 0) //for every other line, reads the ratings
            {
                ArrayList<Integer> rtemp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                while (input.hasNextInt())
                {
                    int tempInt = input.nextInt();
                    rtemp.add(tempInt);
                }               
                allratings.add(rtemp);  

            }


        }
```

For some reason, by the time this while loop is done, int count is at 14. I only want it to be at 8, and think that it should be, considering that there are only 8 lines of text, and it is supposed to execute for each line. Obviously, this causes big problems later in the program. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Does the file have empty lines like your example is showing?

Comment: Yes, including spaces it turns out to be 14 which I think is correct.

Comment: No it doesn't. I just had to do that to format it.

Comment: It has spaces between the integers, but no spaces between the lines.

Comment: So bizarre, even when I cut it down to two lines, the loop still thinks it's read three. I am 100% positive there are no blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your second loop, the cursor never moves to the next line...I added below lines just after your  `allratings.add(rtemp);`  and it worked.

```
if(input.hasNext())
  input.next();
```

Comment: You, my friend, are a genius.